# Convergence of a series with absolute value

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(3z)^n}{2^{|n|}}$ I should study the convergence calculate the sum.

It looks like a geometric series with $q=\frac{3z}{2} $ and sum $\frac{1}{1-q}$.

There are two things that I don't know how to handle:

1. The fact that it starts from $-\infty$;

2. The absolute value of n in the denominator.

Comment: "Series" is both the plural and singular.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you! (English is not my first language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series equals
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(3z)^n}{2^{|n|}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{2}z\right)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(6z\right)^{-n}-1\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{2}z}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{6z}}-1
=\frac{2}{2-3z}+\frac{1}{6z-1}\\
&=\frac{9z}{(2-3z)(6z-1)}.
\end{align}
Fortunately, there is a common convergence ring $\,\frac{1}{6}<|z|<\frac{2}{3}$ for us to do analytic continuation and the result is single-valued. But this is always a thing to check.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why is, in the second series, $6z$ ?

Comment: I changed the variable from $n$ to $-n$. The absolute value $|n|$ always puts the $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: I may miss something, because this looks new to me. Could you explain why, or link me a demonstration?

Comment: A Laurent series is convergent over a ring-shaped region. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series. Analytic continuation allows us to go outside the ring. But the result is not always single-valued.

Comment: It's just the $2$ in the denominator that I don't get.

Comment: OK. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^0\frac{(3z)^n}{2^{|n|}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^0\frac{(3z)^n}{2^{-n}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^0(6z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(6z)^{-n}$.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. It's very clear now. Thank you for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Break the sum into $n\ge0$ and $n\lt0$. This will give you the sum of two geometric series. Remember that $z^{-n}=\left(\frac1z\right)^n$.